# WordPress autoplay - remove "Tap here and unmute" button

Tags: wordpress, vimeo, elementor, autoplay, mute

While the VIMEO video header automatically starts to play, you can see a BUTTON at the top, which says "Tap here and unmute" (only, when you open it on your smartphone - not in ELEMENTOR itself). When I click this button, nothing happens and it does not disappear. I came across this problem after my optimation for smartphone, where I embedded the VIMEO video via a video background section in WordPress Elementor.
The video shall be muted - I even did not upload it with sound on VIMEO. All I wish is to remove the button, so that it does not show up on the smartphone and so that the video can play silently just as in the desktop version.
Best wishes
Marc
[You can see the irritating button on the top of the page...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wm2Bi.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an extra parameter - "?background=1"